# How to publish single sensor_msgs/LaserScan over ROS from two sick_tim sensor

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I publish single sensor_msgs/LaserScan over ROS from  two sick_tim sensor.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204267/how-to-publish-single-sensor_msgs/laserscan-over-ros-from-two-sick_tim-sensor/) by [naka](https://answers.ros.org/users/21711/naka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned by Lorenz on this thread:
http://answers.ros.org/question/37794/using-multiple-laserscan/
It seems that you can simply publish on the same topic from multiple laser scan sources, since each laser scan message includes frame and time information to differentiate. For this you have to set up your URDF correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Valts](https://answers.ros.org/users/7561/valts/) with karma: 41 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't, and you probably don't need to.

The ROS LaserScan message represents a scan in polar coordinates - as an angle and an offset from a center point. Since your laser scanners don't have the same center point, it doesn't make sense to put data from both lasers into the same message.

If you describe your robot and your application in more detail, we can probably help you find a better way to do what you're trying to do. (For example, the navigation stack supports multiple lasers).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naka](https://answers.ros.org/users/21711/naka/) on 2015-03-04**:
I want to move my robot with the navigation stack!
The sick_tim sensors are installed in front and back of the robot.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-05**:
If you're just trying to use your lasers with the navigation stack, you should use two separate topics and configure two observation sources for navigation.